# Accepted term for "noun of action"

Tags: terminology, nouns

Is there an accepted English term for a noun that

- is formed from a verb, and
- means the act or process of doing that verb?

For example, *attraction*, *completion*, *confusion*, *establishment*, *encouragement* and so on.  Each of these examples is formed by adding *-ion* or *-ment* to a common verb.

Is there a word (or short phrase) for a noun like this?

Comment: They’re all essentially types of _verbal nouns_. That’s usually more limited when talking about English (being limited to just gerundial forms like _attracting_, _completing_, etc.); but when discussing various other languages, the term is applied more broadly to any verb that is nominalised from a verbal stem and has the meaning ‘the act/process of Xing’ or ‘an instance of Xing’, regardless of derivation, and there really isn’t any objective reason the same shouldn’t be applicable when discussing English.

Comment: I think you mean gerundial nouns, as in "I witnessed the **killing** of the birds" / "I approved the **breaking** of the seal."

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something slightly wider than "gerundial" or "gerund", which (as far as I understand) really only applies to the forms ending in _-ing_.  That's why I gave examples ending in _-ment_ and _-ion_.  Another possible suffix is _-al_, as in _refusal_ and _withdrawal_.

Comment: The process is called 'nominalisation', and the resultant base is called a 'deverbal noun'. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, after doing a bit more research, I've come to believe that _"deverbal noun"_ is the correct term.  If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Done, as requested.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Note that _deverbal noun_ is a broader category than _verbal noun_ (in the broader sense used when describing other languages): a deverbal noun is **any** noun that’s derived from a verb, regardless of its meaning. So from the verb _employ_, the ‘broad verbal noun’ _employment_ is a deverbal noun, but so are _employ_ (‘in the employ of’), _employer_ and _employee_, none of which are verbal nouns.

Comment: A lot of people would have to google/bing/firefox/whatever their favorite search engine is to find this Linguistics StackExchange, does that makes Google/Bing/Firefox action nouns? Does capitalization matter--Google is a noun, google is a verb/noun of action?

Comment: @MòòbLajleeb I've converted your answer to a comment, since it doesn't really answer the question. But if you're interested in exploring this topic further, feel free to ask a new question using the "Ask Question" button in the top right!

Answer (score 5):

*Event nominalization*: the turning something (a verb) into a noun meaning the event of performing the action denied by the verb.

Strictly speaking this term would include cases of nominalization from clauses rather than plain verbs in languages that support it. To exclude these you could use *lexical event nominalization*.

There is some description on Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization. The section on Japanese has a basic example of clausal nominalization.

When you’re talking strictly about nouns and not NPs, you can also use “(deverbal) event noun”.

Comment: I like this.  It's not exactly what I was looking for - I wanted a term for the noun itself, not the process of making the noun.  But "nominalization" is still a useful term for me.  Also, the article that you linked to introduces the term "process noun" near the bottom.  I think that's the expression I wanted.  So thank you.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes or “event noun”, as not all events are processes.

Answer (score 4):

I've typically seen nouns such as these described as ***action nouns*** or ***event nouns*** (action nouns typically refer to the process in the abstract, whilst event nouns refer to a specific instance). Depending on the semantics of the verb, action and event may feel like a little of a misnomer (e.g. attention doesn't feel like either an action or an event, but would still be seen as an action noun).

Answer (score 1):

The process is called 'nominalisation', and the resultant base is called a 'deverbal noun'.

A few less common suffixes attaching to verbs include *dom, ship and ure*:

*free* + *dom* = *freedom*

*tutor* + *ship* = *tutorship*

*depart* + *ure* = *departure*

Comment: "deverbal noun" also covers any other nouns derived from verbs though, like *speaker* or *addressee*. And although "nominalization" is strictly speaking indeed the term for the process, it is commonly used for the end result as well.

Comment: @Keelan Of course. The ones I gave were just examples.

Comment: Oh, OK.  What I'm looking for wouldn't include words like _speaker_ or _employee_.  I specifically want a noun that means the action of doing something.  I think _departure_ and _tutorship_ both fit what I want (although I'm starting to doubt _tutorship_).  _Freedom_ definitely doesn't.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I see you've unticked it, so now it's no longer the right answer?

Comment: @BillJ, I explained I was looking for a term that strictly means the action or the process associated with the verb.  Your comment above indicates that you agree with Keelan's analysis - that _deverbal noun_ could also mean words like _speaker_ or _addressee_ - which means it's not the term I'm looking for.  Is Keelan's analysis wrong?  Or is there a better term than _deverbal noun_?  Please guide me here!

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I've told you what I think and I stand by it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem how about “(deverbal) event noun”?

Comment: _They freed the prisoners_ ~ _The prisoners got their freedom_.